# Как в MS Sql 2005 вывести последнюю запись в столбце?

Tags: sql-server

Как в MS Sql 2005 вывести последнюю запись в столбце?

Comment: это не первичный ключ(

Answer (score 2):

Если есть первичный ключ , например Id типа int, тогда последнюю запись можно получить так:

```
Select top(1) * from Table order by Id desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table where table.id = (select max(id) from table)
```